# Yii 2 - Class 'CArrayDataProvider' not found

Tags: php, yii

I'm new at yii and trying to find my way around. I have done a tutorial or two. I then decided to start editing/changing the example to allow me to learn more. I created a page that does a simple PING. That gets validated. On success, it loads a static page. This all works.

What I wanted to do next is to see how I can utilize a grid to populate that with some data. My real life example is the same. I will get a array of data coming in.

It seems that CArrayDataProvider is what I need. So, I am trying to get a very simple example to work. If I get this to work, I can move on.

I have tried a whole bunch of examples. The error is the same every time. It seems that I do not have CArrayDataProvider installed? If that is even possible.

I did a standard basic install:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-basic basic
```

I have the following at the beginning of my controllers file:

```
use yii2\data\ArrayDataProvider;
```

I get no error here.
I searched for the file itself on the file system, could not find it. I did find ArrayDataProvider, so I tried that, same result:

```
use vendor\yiisoft\yii2\data\ArrayDataProvider;
```

The error is:

```
PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException
Class 'CArrayDataProvider' not found
```

This is on line 24:

```
"dataProvider = new CArrayDataProvider($fruits);"
```

Here is my example code. Not that I think the issue is in here, but to show what I am trying to do:

```
$fruits = array(  
  array('id' => 1, 'name'=>'apple', 'color' => 'green'),  
  array('id' => 2, 'name'=>'orange', 'color' => 'orange'),  
  array('id' => 3, 'name'=>'banana', 'color' => 'yellow'),  
  array('id' => 4, 'name'=>'pineapple', 'color' => 'brown')  
);  

$dataProvider = new CArrayDataProvider($fruits);  

$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(  
  'id' => 'fruits-grid',  
  'dataProvider' => $dataProvider ,  
  'columns' => array(  
    array(  
        'name' => 'ID',  
        'value' => '$data["id"]',  
    ),  
    array(  
        'name' => 'Name',  
        'value' => '$data["name"]'  
    ),  
    array(  
        'name' => 'Color',  
        'value' => '$data["color"]'  
    ),  
  )  
));
```

On the file-system (linux) itself I did a update:

```
composer update
```

I have been Googling for the last 2 days and I am finding nothing.

I tried adding a date picket. That worked. I used:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/yii/yii_extensions.htm

So in short, the static page that I call, now displays a DateTimePicker.

At the start of the file I added:

```
use kartik\datetime\DateTimePicker;
```

And in the body:

```
<?php
  echo DateTimePicker::widget([
     'name' => 'dp_1',
     'type' => DateTimePicker::TYPE_INPUT,
     'value' => '23-Feb-1982 10:10',
     'pluginOptions' => [
        'autoclose'=>true,
        'format' => 'dd-M-yyyy hh:ii'
     ]
  ]);
?>
```

How do I get yii2 to allow me to use ArrayDataProvider. Or how do I install the extension? Or who do I reference it?

Comment: as you are using yii2 you must use `ArrayDataProvider` instead of `CArrayDataProvider` as this is in yii 1.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Yii2 there's not a `CArrayDataProvider`. Use `ArrayDataProvider`, like described in docs:

```
$provider = new yii\data\ArrayDataProvider([
   'allModels' => $query->from('post')->all(),
   'sort' => [
       'attributes' => ['id', 'username', 'email'],
   ],
   'pagination' => [
       'pageSize' => 10,
   ],
]);
```

Pretty well documented [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-arraydataprovider.html).

Comment: Hi. Now I get this error: Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException

Setting unknown property: yii\data\ArrayDataProvider::0

Comment: Open the docs, and see what you should provide under `$fruits` variable. It's really good documented...

Answer (score 0):

Yii2 supports `ArrayDataProvider` and yii 1.* supports CArrayDataProvider, so as per your code you are using Yii2, so just replace the below line with

```
$dataProvider = new CArrayDataProvider($fruits);
```

With this:

```
$dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider($fruits);
```

Comment: "Same" error. I get "PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException

Class 'ArrayDataProvider' not found". In my controllers file I tried both use yii2\data\ArrayDataProvider; and 
use vendor\yiisoft\yii2\data\ArrayDataProvider;. Still same error.

Answer (score 0):

Thx to everyone's help! I now have a working example.

In case anyone else has the same issues, I will post my working code here:

```
use kartik\grid\GridView;


$resultData = [
array("id"=>1,"name"=>"Cyrus","email"=>"risus@consequatdolorvitae.org"),
array("id"=>2,"name"=>"Justin","email"=>"ac.facilisis.facilisis@at.ca"),
array("id"=>3,"name"=>"Mason","email"=>"in.cursus.et@arcuacorci.ca"),
array("id"=>4,"name"=>"Fulton","email"=>"a@faucibusorciluctus.edu"),
array("id"=>5,"name"=>"Neville","email"=>"eleifend@consequatlectus.com"),
array("id"=>6,"name"=>"Jasper","email"=>"lectus.justo@miAliquam.com"),
array("id"=>7,"name"=>"Neville","email"=>"Morbi.non.sapien@dapibusquam.org"),
array("id"=>8,"name"=>"Neville","email"=>"condimentum.eget@egestas.edu"),
array("id"=>9,"name"=>"Ronan","email"=>"orci.adipiscing@interdumligulaeu.com"),
array("id"=>10,"name"=>"Raphael","email"=>"nec.tempus@commodohendrerit.co.uk"),     
];


$dataProvider = new \yii\data\ArrayDataProvider([
    'key'=>'id',
    'allModels' => $resultData,
    'sort' => [
        'attributes' => ['id', 'name', 'email'],
    ],
]); 


echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,

    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'id',

        [
        'attribute' => 'name', 
        'value' => 'name',
        ],
        [
        "attribute" => "email",
        'value' => 'email',
        ]

  ]
]);
```